Use ComboBox for datagridview column when datagridview has a table as datasource
I code in C# with VS 2019. Since I an novice in C#, I am appealing to this forum.
I have a DataGridView binned to DataTable.  I would like assign a cell value from a ComboBox.   Displaying a ComboBox at Cursor Position does not always shows the ComboBox.
From the other hand I don't know how to use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn when DataGridView is binned to Table.
I have created a DataGridView.  On CellMouseDown I have located the ComboBox at Cursor position, and turn it visible,  hopping assign cell from selected item of  ComboBox.
The problem is that the ComboBox does not shows up.
